texstudio_ojwqxY.tex: error: 163: Bad math environment delimiter. \[ \begin{equation}
\[ \begin{equation} \alpha = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
        m_{1} & m_{2} & \dots & m_{n} \\
        k_{1} & k_{2} & \dots & k_{n} \end{array} \right), \end{equation}\]\\

Beside it I also am getting the error:
texstudio_ojwqxY.tex: error: 165: Bad math environment delimiter. ...{n} \end{array} \right), \end{equation}\]

and
texstudio_ojwqxY.tex: error: 165: Missing $ inserted. ...{n} \end{array} \right), \end{equation}\]

and
texstudio_ojwqxY.tex: error: 165: Missing \endgroup inserted. ...k_{n} \end{array} \right), \end{equation}
and texstudio_ojwqxY.tex: error: 165: \begin{equation*} on input line 163 ended by \end{equation}. ...k_{n} \end{array} \right), \end{equation}.

And when I did the above another error also started at  \end{center}:
texstudio_ojwqxY.tex: error: 183: \begin{document} ended by \end{center}. \end{center}

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

BTW, if you have \usepackage{amsmath} (or \documentclass{amsart}), then you can change \left( \begin{array}{cccc} ... \end{array} \right) to \begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}.

\[ \begin{equation}
is an error. \[ starts display math, then \begin{equation} would start display math again, so it's an error.
Use \[ if you just want the math, use \begin{equation} if you also want an equation number. Do not use both at the same time.
